# Typeahead.js - template settings ignored

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I'm trying to setup custom template with Typeahead.js

My code is:

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
    },queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 100,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://www.domain.com/json.php?action=countries&q=%QUERY'
    }
});

countries.initialize();

$('.lang').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'countries',
    source: countries.ttAdapter(),
    template: [
        '<p class="lang-id">{{lang_id}}</p>',
        '<p class="value">{{value}}</p>'
    ].join(''),
    engine: Hogan
});
```

It works fine, but the template setting is ignored - I still get default dropdown. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I also tried:

```
$('input').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'countries',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: countries.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
     empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
      'no results found',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> – {{id}}</p>'
  },
  engine: Hogan
});
```

which throws an error:

`Property 'suggestion' of object #<Object> is not a function`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), you can see that the name is `templates` and not `template` - like in you show in your second example. The issue you have there is that `suggestion` needs to be a function, not a string. In the bottom example of custom templates you can see they use `Handlebars.compile` which returns a function which takes a single parameter containing the data to render a template with - and returns a string that is the generated HTML. If you do not want to use `Handlebars` you could do something like (please note that for simplicity I do not escape the data in my example. For a proper solution you should escape `data.value` and `data.id` to make sure you do not introduce XSS vulnerabilities):

```
$('input').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'countries',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: countries.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
     empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
      'no results found',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: function(data){
      return '<p><strong>' + data.value + '</strong> - ' + data.id + '</p>';
    }
  },
  engine: Hogan
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! Is there any advantage in using Handelbars vs Hogan?

Comment: I do not really know Hogan at all, so I may be completely wrong here. But looking slightly at the documentation it looks pretty decent - I would guess that you can go with either without any problem.

Comment: I see a lot of examples with the join('\n') part. Why is + not used instead?

Comment: Its dirtier. try it. unecessary +'s in every newline of an htmlis not my idea of clean

Comment: For some reason, using this code, data in suggestion function call is undefined for me.

Comment: It's *undefined* because it has to be an actual record field, like **data.name**, etc.

Comment: it's undefined because data is not an object like the one returned by the ajax call. I get the same problem, then if I print data into the console, I get  Object { _query="whateveryouenter"}, any idea?

Comment: Is there any any way to add a right aligned font-awesome icon at the end of the suggestion data?